# Regex fails with decimal digits (.00) causes preg_match() to return FALSE

Tags: php, regex, string, floating-point, preg-match

I've got a prize input field in my form. Valid user input should always look like this:

```
1.00
0.00
10000.20
100.25
```

Before the floating point there could be unlimited digits, after only 2 digits. I tried to achieve this with that regex:

```
/^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]{2})$/
```

If you check this out here: https://regex101.com/ there is a match for the value `10.00`.

But now in PHP I used `preg_match()` as follows:

```
!preg_match('/^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]{2})$/', $obj->getPrize());
```

- 10.00 returns true
- 10.01 returns false

Can anyone explain the difference? Why does `10.00` return true? I think `preg_match()` handles zeros differently, but how to achieve this task?

Comment: You were very close to the source of the problem! Maybe for next time just always `var_dump();` everything and check if it is that way you expect it to be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the regex. It's your numbers, because PHP just trims your 0's if you don't have any necessary numbers at the end. You can see this with this code:

```
$num = 10.00;
var_dump($num);

$num = 10.01;
var_dump($num);
```

output:

```
float(10)
float(10.01)
```

As you can see in the first output there is no `.00` simply because you don't have any numbers after it.  But your regex requiers 2 digits after `.` and that is why your regex fails.

Now one solution can be just to make `\.([0-9]{2})` optional, e.g.

```
^([0-9]+)(?:\.([0-9]{2}))?$
```

Comment: he can also check for deimal part before feeding to regex, `if( ($number - (int)$number) == 0 )`, then do whatever

Comment: Same as in MySQL, zeros getting trimmed until a representation is given. So I can't preserve them? Then I have to add them manually in the view afterwards?